# Excel - convert row cells into comma separted list

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet containing 2 rows. Each row has the data inserted into multiple columns. What I need is to generate a comma separated list based on all the logic if its 08:00 a.m. then 0 if is p.m. then 1 like this:

```
0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
```

On the second row I have the same, but here I can have empty cells, if I have an empty cell, so I should get something like:

```
0.8,0.8,0.7,0.8,,,,,
```

[image]

> Any clue?

Comment: [if function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)  and [textjoin function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Comment: This is what worked, want to do the anwer so i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first row, you can use a combination of TextJoin and Round. Rounding 8 AM down will result in 0, rounding 8 PM will result in 1.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,ROUND(A1:H1,0))
```

The second row can be served with

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:H2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to get the results as a new file, you can export/save the spreadsheet as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` formula to convert the first row to 0 and 1, then convert the file to a csv file.

Comment: I have to have the comma separated value in a field

Comment: What do you mean by field?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using **`#PowerQuery`** (available in **Excel 2010 and later versions**) apart from formula based solution.

The logic is to add the data to the power query editor, use the **Replace Values** function under the `Transform` tab to replace `08:00 a. m.` with `1` and replace `08:00 p. m.` with `0`, and then use **Merge Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to merge all columns with comma `,` as the delimiter. The outcome may look like the following. You can load the result to a new worksheet (by default) or create a connection to this query and load it to a specific location but the limitation is that it has to be in a **Table**.

[image: Power Query]

Here is the full power query m code behind the scene for reference only. All functions are performed using built-in functions.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="YourTable"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type any}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, {"Column4", type any}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","08:00 a. m.",1,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","08:00 p. m.",0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value1", {{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}}, "en-AU"),{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```